# How to relocate paypal button gateway on checkout page in woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

Is it possible to move paypal checkout button to another place on the screen?

[image]

Right now the paypal button is on regular gateway form, I would like to move it to `woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details` action.

I was at first using the filter below, but it refers only to placing order button and not paypal button.

```
<?php
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', '<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" >test</button>' ); // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine 
?>
```

How to relocate paypal button gateway on checkout page in woocommerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

E.g. the paypal button function name is `woo_custom_paypal_button`.

Then add action like this into your `function.php` or specific plugin:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'woo_custom_paypal_button' );
```

Or if there's something that's already displayed there, and you might want to remove it, first find the function name and then try like this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'woo_function_to_remove' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'woo_custom_paypal_button');
```

**Update**

I tried this code and worked in my case:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'x_relocate_paypal_button' );
function x_relocate_paypal_button() {
    $cls = new WC_Gateway_PPEC_With_SPB;
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', array( $cls, 'display_paypal_button' ), 20 );
}
```

Just replace the `woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details` hook to relocate to another position.
You can find more visual hook guide on checkout page on [this article](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-checkout-page/).

Comment: `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'woo_custom_paypal_button' not found or invalid function name`

I'm receiving this error, I can't create my own custom woocommerce paypal button, since I wont be able to connect him to woocommerce (or atleast I don't know how).

Comment: That error is showing because there is no function for woo_custom_paypal_button.
You need to replace woo_custom_paypal_button with the valid function name from the Paypal button plugin you're using. If you don't know, just ask the plugin developer or check the code in the plugin.

Comment: Basically it's made by woocommerce https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-express-checkout/  - But I can't see any developer related to my topic information in the docs.

Comment: I have updated my previous answer. Please test it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and moved the button into the review order div:

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_paypal_payments_checkout_button_renderer_hook', function() {
    return 'woocommerce_review_order_after_submit';
});
```

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-paypal-payments/wiki/Actions-and-Filters#change-button-placement-via-render-hooks

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-checkout-page/